# Python: how would I write a keyevent?

Tags: python, events, keypress

So simply put I want my code to call a event like OnKeyPress("Keyname") or something, each time I press a key. I don't want to use tkinter.

I have a Update method that gets called 20 times a second that's in a parent class
I have several child classes that have that function called. On some of them I want to use a key press event to make parts of my robot I am working on move.(eg: while I am pressing the up arrow the robot will move foreword) tkinter is well not designed for this its more for drawing content on a screen and I want to make my code more efficient for its purpous. also I would prefer to have my own then use a pre-made one so I can get a better understanding on how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I urge you to reconsider not using tkinter.  Ignoring the GUI stuff, it has a tested, cross-platform, *asynchonous* event loop system that handles both scheduled (timed) events and key press and release events.  And it is written in C and updated as platforms change.  (See the comments for the recipe @Ty quoted about platform changes.)  You will find it very difficult to reproduce the same facilities in Python.

Usage would start with

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()  # make the window invisible
```

Thereafter, one can ignore the GUI stuff and only use root.bind(key event, function) and root.after(milleseconds, function, *args).  (In the meanwhile, the option to use graphics to interact with the robot, in the future, would still be there.)

Given existing move_forward and stop_move functions, here is how to make a robot move while pressing up-arrow.

```
root.bind('<KeyPress-Up>', move_forward)
root.bind('<keyRelease-Up>' stop_move)
```

About the importance of being asynchronous (non-blocking): I presume you call an update function 20 times a second by calling time.sleep(.05) between each update.  This is a blocking call and during this period your code is frozen.  It cannot do anything and cannot respond to events.

Suppose you develop two or more animations for the robot: say one for the arms, one for the head (or whatever is appropriate for your robot).  Each would consist of a series times commands, implemented by root.after calls.  Now suppose you want to run two or more animations in parallel.  Assuming that each only requires a small fraction of CPU time, this would be trivial with tkinter because each would run asynchronously and not block the program from doing other things.  With a blocking event system, you would have to write a new animation each each combination you want.

Comment: one of the reasons why I did not want to use tkinter was because I found that some of its features were not thread safe. Can I trust root.bind to run in threads? Also What do you mean by asynchronous? You are right the update is called after waiting for a sleep But sleep is only called after all Updates have been called. and I can have as many objects as I want each with there own update that runs one after the other I tested it out with 200 objects and they still finished under a single tick.

Comment: Creation of widgets 'must' be done in the main thread.  I know that some widget manipulations can be done from other threads, because I have tried it in response to bug reports.  (Current 3.x works much better that even current 2.7.  I don't know about root.bind.  However, this should not be an issue as all tk event handlers should be in the main thread.  The main use of threads with tk is for file/web i/o.  A normal read or write in a thread that cannot  be executed immediately blocks the thread.  Then the OS puts it to sleep.  An event handler in the main thread may initiate an i/o thread.

Comment: Synchronous code is executed sequentially except as modified by flow control statements (if, while, for) within functions and call/return between functions.  With a-synchronous code (as used in Python), execution jumps around otherwise.  With tk(inter), the stimulus is timer events and unpredictable user events.  The underlying issue is keeping the CPU busy.  Multiple processes, multiple threads, multiple asyncio tasks (which generally replace threads), and multiple event handlers are all means to this end.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
class _GetchUnix:
    def init(self):
        import tty, sys
    def call(self):
        import sys, tty, termios
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch
class _GetchWindows:
    def init(self):
        import msvcrt
    def call(self):
        import msvcrt
        return msvcrt.getch()
class _Getch:
    def init(self):
        try:
            self.impl = _GetchWindows()
        except ImportError:
            self.impl = _GetchUnix()
```

`def __call__(self): return self.impl()
getch = _Getch()
while True:
    if getch.impl():
        print getch.impl()`

Every thing up to the `while` loop you need. Then when ever you call `getch.impl()` it will wait for a input, but if there is none, it will move on. That's why I used the `while` loop

**DISCLAIMER**
This is not my code, please check out:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/

Comment: mmmm. Sorry but theirs a lot of functions and modules there that i have never ever seen before. If I am going to use it in my code I would first have to understand whats going on and not just simply copy and paste like some script kiddy. I had some one do that with a code containing threads before and they had no Idea what threads were. It was funny to watch them try work out what was going on but also a reminder not to just copy something with out understanding it first.

Comment: I understands what it does